# How to align hub tiles programmatically in wp8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am creating a Windows phone app.
I am creating hub tiles dynamically i.e pragmatically and adding in the stack panel.
I have around 10 hubtiles and what I want is to show in the stack panel 2 in a single row.
I mean let say I have hubtliles as A, B , C , D...

I have to align them as 
A    B
C    D
....

How to do this alignment progmatically

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a 5 row, 2 column grid and assign hub tiles to correct cell programmatically?